# Слияние Symfony2 с другим ресурсом

Tags: apache, symfony2

На данный момент на одном хосте имеется структура
`symfony2.domain.com` (*/var/www/symfony2*) – роут для рабочего симфони 2 проекта
`domain.com` (*/var/www/domain.com*) – сайт на другой платформе.

Задача сделать так, чтобы Симфони была доступна по роуту `domain.com/symfony2` при том без редиректа (сабдомен будет закрыт)

Пока самая простая но кривая идея в реализации организовать структуру каталогов
*/var/www/symfony2/site/base* (в base перенести web)
В apache DocumentRoot установить в */var/www/symfony2/site* 
тогда еще придется игнорить в git директорию site кроме base

Нельзя ли это сделать без разрушений структуры файловой системы?

Answer (score 1):

Более правильным решением оказалось установить ngnix как front-end web server (на 80 порту), domain.com на 8080, symfony2 на 8081 доступными только локально. И с помощью proxy_pass организовать маршрутизацию.

Пример конфигурации ngnix

```
server {
...       
    location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
    location /symfony2 {
            proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1:8081/;
            proxy_set_header X-Real_IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
...
```